# go-swagger how to add tags with descriptions?

Tags: go-swagger

Basically when I am writing my yaml files manually I can always just define a `tags:` section and define my tags one by one after that with `-name:` and `description:`. Is there a way to define these in my go-swagger comments so the generator picks them up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use the workaround approach for go-swagger
That is to specify an input file with your tags in json and pass it to your go generate command.

i.e,

```
//go:generate swagger generate spec --input tags.json -o swagger.json
```

Where tags.json will contain an array of objects of tags,

i.e,

```
{
"tags": [
    {
        "name":"YourRoute1",
        "description":"Your Route 1 Description"
    },
    {
        "name":"YourRoute2",
        "description":"Your Route 2 Description"
    }
  ]
}
```

This would produce an combined output with your tags.json file to your output swagger.json